# Cant read router when testing in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, next.js, jestjs

Hi what I am trying to do is test when button is pressed it redirects to '/'. Regulary it works but when I try to test it it fails giving me this:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')

      71 |                         className={styles.footerButton}
      72 |                         data-testid="footerButton"
    > 73 |                         onClick={() => router.push('/')}
         |
```

This is my test code:

```
const buttonElement = screen.getByTestId('footerButton');
      expect(buttonElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      userEvent.click(buttonElement);

      expect(window.location.href).toBe('http://localhost/');
                                      ^
```

This is the component:

```
<button
                        className={styles.footerButtonPC}
                        data-testid="footerButtonPC"
                        onClick={() => router.push('/')}
                      >
                        Full Fit & Size Guide
                      </button>
```

Im fairly new to react and testing in react in general so any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, what you want is to mock the router, because it's not available in the server context.

Consider trying "next-router-mock"

```
import mockRouter from "next-router-mock";
jest.mock("next/router", () => require("next-router-mock"));
```

Then, in tests, you'll be able to use it in the following ways:

```
mockRouter.push("/your-initial-url"); // Optionally
mockRouter.push = jest.fn(); 

// Act

expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith("http://localhost/");
```